# Using "type" to print out multiple files

Tags: makefile

I have a macro the finds some files and stores them in a variable

```
ERR_FILES += \
$(addprefix $(COMP_DIR)/err/, $(C_SOURCES:.c=.err)) \
$(addprefix $(COMP_DIR)/err/, $(C1_SOURCES:.c=.err)) \
$(addprefix $(COMP_DIR)/err/, $(C2_SOURCES:.c=.err)) \
$(addprefix $(COMP_DIR)/err/, $(S_SOURCES:.s=.era)) \
$(addprefix $(COMP_DIR)/err/, $(ASM_SOURCES:.asm=.era))
```

I want it to "type" each file name out.
type $(ERR_FILES) is what I'm trying to use but it's coming up syntax error.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`type` is not a valid UNIX command.  That's a Windows command.  Try `echo` to print the names of the files, or `cat` to show the contents of the files.